# Render element based on key value from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

Let's say I have json file,

```
[
    {"page":"about","title":"About","order":"0"},
    {"page":"another-test","title":"Another Test"},
    {"page":"how-to","title":"How To","order":"1"},
    {"page":"test-page","title":"Test page","order":"2"}
]
```

Here, you see a key `order`, when I map this json file, I want to render the one with less `order` value first. For example,

```
import myJSON from 'file.json'

....
myJSON.map(({ page, title }) => (
   <h1 key={page}>{title}</h1>
))
....
```

How can I use the `order` key and render the one with the less `order` value or ascending order?

Comment: Use `.sort` to sort the array before rendering?

Comment: If that is the entire contents of your json file, I'm not sure how you are going to be able to `import` it like that.  Typically imports involve the source file `export`ing something

Comment: @Taplar it's likely being converted by webpack during import to a JS object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, yes, sorting did the work, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort them based on order.

```js
myJSON.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.order) - parseInt(b.order))

myJSON.map(({ page, title }) => (
   <h1 key={page}>{title}</h1>
))
```

Answer (score 2):

Rahul's solution has a flaw! Any orthodox solution to this will have this same flaw.

What if the "order" property is undefined as it is in record 2 in myJSON?

```
{"page":"another-test","title":"Another Test"}
```

Then this approach will default to the 0 case (equal values). It will think the undefined value and the value it is comparing it to are equal.

Here is an example:

```
let myJSON = [
   {"page":"about","title":"About","order":"100"},
   {"page":"another-test","title":"Another Test"},
   {"page":"how-to","title":"How To","order":"50"},
   {"page":"test-page","title":"Test page","order":"10"}
]

function myCompareFunc( a, b ) {
  // if a.order or b.order is undefined this is false
  if ( a.order < b.order ){
    return -1; 
  }
  // if a.order or b.order is undefined this is false
  if ( a.order > b.order ){
    return 1;
  }
  // will default to this
  return 0; 
}
myJSON.sort(myCompareFunc);
```

The records that are before the record with the undefined "order" prop will not be sorted against the records that are after. So record 1 and 2 in the json above will keep their places and only record 3 and 4 will be sorted properly against each other and will switch places. Result will be:

```
   {"page":"about","title":"About","order":"100"},
   {"page":"another-test","title":"Another Test"},
   {"page":"test-page","title":"Test page","order":"10"},
   {"page":"how-to","title":"How To","order":"50"}
```

That is not quite sorter is it?

How to fix it? One way is to add this at the start of the compare function:

```
  if ( !a.order ){
    return -1;
  }
```

That will sort all records with undefined "order" prop to the beginning of the array and will not meddle with the records that have a defined "order" prop.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I already filtered the json if it didn't have any `order` at all. And I did it with an if in the render, seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

That structure could be optimised for quicker access.

I'd try to denormalise it a bit and create something like the below example. This enables you to use `Object.keys()` to quickly get all the page ids.

pageData.json

```
{
  "about": {
    "id": "about",
    "title": "About",
    "order":100
  },
  "another-test": {
    "id": "another-test",
    "title": "Another Test"
  }
}
```

The solution to the inital query of finding out which pages had order would be

```js
import pageData from '...'

const pageKeys = Object.keys(pageData);
const pagesThatHaveOrder = pageKeys.filter(key => !pageData[key].order)
```

Comment: I generate that json during build, each time. What it happens actually is, I collect `yaml` data from some files and structure is not important here.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info @Hasan. If I were you and there were no contraints from elsewhere I would optime that generated json for access. I've updated the above answer with code that could find the pages without order in that structure. Hope it's useful! 

Comment: @alanionita, great, but I am actually using an if before rending to check if `order` exists. Seems simpler. You can check [here at the repo](https://github.com/IamLizu/humous/blob/7e6b5a1b8e09968bbee22cd6d7fc902899ae29a1/components/layout.jsx#L37)